# How to receive serial strings in Simulink

Tags: matlab, serial-port, simulink

I am trying to read a stream of strings from serial input (COM Port) and then display the strings. The issue I am having is that the strings are of variable length and Simulink only seems to be able to read a string if I specify its length in the data size field.

For instance, if I specify a data size of [1 18], I only receive those strings which are of length 18 or have lengths greater than 18. If I specify [1 80], I only receive strings of length 80 or greater and so forth. If the string is longer than the specified size then the string is truncated to the specified size.

I have not been able to resolve this issue and the documentation is very light on how to use (and specify) this parameter. The data size is described as "*Output data size, or the number of values that should be read at each simulation time step. This parameter is specified as a multidimensional numeric array. The data size does not include the header or terminator values*".

[image]

Any help in solving this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "slightly shorter"?

Comment: @Adriaan If I set the data size to x, then I will receive the last x characters of all strings which are at least x characters long. Those which have lengths less than x do not appear at all. I have edited my question, the first description was incorrect.

Comment: Right, so the problem is that setting the size to `1` would truncate every string, whereas setting it to `inf` wouldn't capture anything